# FullCalendar : No header for timeGridWeek outside ValidRange

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar 5.5.0 with Angular 10.

Something kind of annoying appears during the migration (fullcalendar v4 -> v5), there is no longer a header for the date before the start of the validRange :
[image: example]

With the parameters :

```js
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    validRange: {
      start: "2021-01-22",
      end: "2022-01-01"
    },
```

Adding a `visibleRange` doesn't change anything.

Well, it will save my day if someone know if it's a known bug, (or a feature), and how to fix this without adding custom code and `.revert()` to any action on event (move, resize, ...).

Thanks !

**PS**: you can easily try it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-hertz-x4etl?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can check for known bugs / issues on fullCalendar's GitHub pages, and raise an issue yourself if you need to. We can't deal with internal fullCalendar bugs here, we can only deal with questions about implementation of fullCalendar into web pages, and configuration etc

Comment: I did it already ;), but it seems to be a feature ...

Comment: Ok. There's nothing we can do about it then, apart from raising a feature request for it to be changed back.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `firstDay:{getDay(new Date())}` it get the day number and start the calendar from that date